# why is so hard in linux to change permantly hostname?

Tags: linux, hostname

Suddenly, my machine changed its hostname for unknown reason. I want to set the previous hostname. I can change hostname, very easily temporarily but not permantly!
when I say hostname I mean the word that it appears at terminal after username eg.
`username@hostname :~$`

What I did:

- added `"kernel.hostname = name" in /etc/sysctl.conf` - no change after reboot.
- `echo 'name' > /proc/sys/kernel/hostname` only temporarily change it
- `hostnamectl set-hostname name` only temporarily change it
- `sudo hostname name`   only temporarily change it
- `cat /etc/hostname` already contains "name"
- `sudo sysctl -w kernel.hostname=name` - no change after reboot.

problems if change temporarily hostname from terminal when using sudo

- `Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified`
- without changing current hostname system output `cannot connect to display:0`. This message is gone when I change (temporarily) hostname to the proper hostname.  I believe somehow system has kept my previous hostname and it conflicts.

so, until now, i am out of options. any suggestion?

Comment: Out of curiosity. 1) What did the hostname suddenly change to? 2) Does it remain changed if you boot with network disabled?

Comment: I think after some thundestorm, hostname changed! Not tried with network disabled!

Comment: What distribution are you using? The answer may vary

Answer (score 1):

For Debian distributions the primary point for changing the hostname is to edit `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`, and then reboot.

There may be secondary considerations within specific applications and subsystems. For example, here is one I consider on my systems:

- Exim4 MTA subsystem: edit `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf` or run `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to change hostname permantly.
Changes in /etc/sysctl.conf are not automatically written to kernel!

However, after running

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.hostname=name and/or
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf  to add `kernel.hostname=name`
```

Changes are applied to kernel by using

```
sudo sysctl -p --system -w
```

So, I think debian distributions something is missing here?

UPDATE:
if your hostname is changing to `easy` or any other name than yours, please consider that:
`sudo nano /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.enp3s0.leases`
and change it. If not there, `sudo grep -rnw -e easy` to find where it lies.

Comment: "_Changes in /etc/sysctl.conf are not automatically written to kernel_" - they are written at boot time